# How to record streaming video using HTML or HTML5?

Tags: html, browser, video-streaming, record

NOT recording using webcam or microphone...
But record (and also save) the video that is currently streaming or playing in the browser.

Comment: This is no programming related question. There are other Sites in the StackExchange network, better suitable for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for not-live videos from youtube and the like: Use browser developer tools. For example firefox web developer tools network tab open go to the page and look for the get respond that has return type of video/* (video/mp4 in youtube) right click on it and select open in new tab and then just use browser's save (CTRL-S) to save the video. I believe this to work similiarly in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use developer tools of your browser to see all network traffic and save the video stream.